# Vertically allign 3 figures in one page in latex

Tags: latex

I've exported 3 figures from R studio (in .png). How can I vertically align them on one page using latex?
That's my attempt

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subfloat[Germany, sectors C26 to C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{Images/deu.png}%
}

\subfloat[Italy, sectors C29-C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{Images/ITA.png}%
}
\subfloat[United States, sectors C29-C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{Images/USA.png}%
}


\caption{Offshoring level. \\Source: Elaborated data from WIOT and SEA tables (2016).}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "vertically align them"? Do you want the images one below each other?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to have the images one below each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your image one below each other, insert an empty line between each `\subfloat`. This empty line will insert a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering 

\subfloat[Germany, sectors C26 to C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}

\subfloat[Italy, sectors C29-C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}

\subfloat[United States, sectors C29-C30]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
}


\caption{Offshoring level. \\Source: Elaborated data from WIOT and SEA tables (2016).}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]